# Checkmarx waring for beforeEach method: Use of Deprecated or Obsolete Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, jestjs, checkmarx

I have generated **checkmarx** report for React application.

**Error:** Use of Deprecated or Obsolete Functions.

**Description:**

Method beforeEach in **GetPrefix.test.js,** calls an obsolete API, CxAssociativeArray_6e1319b2. This has been deprecated, and should not be used in a modern codebase.

**Code:**

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules() // CLear the cache
        process.env = { ...OLD_ENV } // Make copy of old/empty environment
        delete process.env.NODE_ENV
    })
```

**How to resolve this checkmarx issue ?**

Comment: Did you find out how to fix this issue?